# Sending keyboard input with batch commands

Tags: batch-file, cmd, colors, echo, enter

we want our .bat file to send the "Enter" key every second. Is it possible? If so, how are we supposed to do that?

Will `%SendKeys% {ENTER}` work?

Our code currently:

```
@echo off
cls
color 0a
:loop
%SendKeys% {ENTER}
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
goto :loop
```

Comment: Not without a third party program. But Vbscript and Jscript can do what you want and do not require any third party program because the windows script host is installed by default.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to send keys in batch files without using a third party utility or VBScript. Here is a hybrid VBScript-batch file that sends the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key every 1 second(s) continuously.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
    set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
    cls
    color 0a
    :loop
        %SendKeys% "{ENTER}"
        timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
    goto :loop

@end

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

*NOTE: To change the keys inputted simply change the `{enter}` value.*

Answer (score 1):

first download nircmd from here: http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/
create a batch file in the same directory where nircmd is and type:

```
@echo off
:loop
nircmd sendkeypress enter
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
goto :loop
```